# How to host a Portal 2 co-op session?

Tags: portal-2

I would like to host my own Portal 2 online game for others to join (across the Internet), but I'm not sure how. I only know how to *join* games. I'm running on PC, by the way. Sorry for being a noob. :P

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch Portal 2
2. Click *Play cooperative game*
3. Click one of the two modes
4. A list of friends will appear, invite at least one friend

Game will start automatically when they accept your invite.

Comment: No, I meant over the Internet with a stranger.

Comment: then say so, for step 4 just click the button at the bottom _find partner online_ that will randomly select someone else who has pushed that button too.

Comment: I understand that, but I always play as P-body. My goal is to play as Atlas (as he is the session admin), but I've never played as him.

Comment: @CallumB. I always thought the assignment was random. There is no difference between the two...

Comment: @CallumB. I assume the host is the one which has a better connection, there will probably be some sort of connection test and then it would be assigned based on that.